# React component being rendered with old props

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
var Answer = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {edit: false, comments: []}
  },

componentWillMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/answers/' + this.props.answer.id + '/comments/',
        success: function(data){
            this.setState({comments: data});

        }
    });
},

render: function(){
    return ( 
        <div>
             //This renders with initial comments in the state, the empty array
            <Comments comments={this.state.comments} /> 
        </div>
    );
},
```

notice how I fetch comments from the server and save them into state then pass them as props to comments. Problem is the props are being passed as the old state, not the new state that's fetched from the server. What am I missing here?

Comment: How does your Comments component look like?

Answer (score 2):

Alright I figured it out after some thought. The problem was that `render` is being called before `componentWillMount`, so the child component `Comments` was being rendered with the initial props the first time, so I needed to let the child component know that it will receive new props when the parent set its state. I added this code to my child component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
        this.setState({comments: newProps.comments})
    },
```

Comment: You should not represent the same data as state in at two different levels of your component hierarchy. It should be maintained as state at the highest level, and passed down as props. Your child component should refer to this data as this.props.comments. Otherwise you have two sources of truth for this data which is not idiomatic React.

Comment: @John Oh thanks man, that's a great point, I will do some refactoring now I guess.

Comment: What if the child component has an i/o responsibility, wouldn't state be necessary then so you are not waiting for slow prop passing?